# calling controller action from Vuejs, from different views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vue.js

I have (topbar + sidebar + bottombar) as Vuejs components that are part of page layout within every View is rendered.
In top bar vuejs file i have a method that is loading "some" data via API request to one of my controller:

```
    beforeMount() {  
        this.loggedUserDeputies.userDeputies = [];
        console.log("calling LoadLoggedUserDeputies");
        $.get('api/Timesheets/LoadLoggedUserDeputies')
            .then(response => response as Promise<LoggedUserDeputies>)
            .then(data => {
                this.loggedUserDeputies = data;               
            });         
    },
```

API controller method:

```
    [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    public object LoadLoggedUserDeputies()
    {
        if (ActualUserContract.LoggedUserDeputies == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var result = ActualUserContract.LoggedUserDeputies
             .ToList()
             .Select(x => new
             {
                 userContractId = x.UserContract.Id,
                 userContractFullName = x.UserFullName,
                 userContractPersonalNumber = x.UserContract.PersonalNumber
             });
        return new { userDeputies = result };
    }
```

but i have an issue, that the url for fetch the data is always modified based on current view i am in.

(so instead of always call: `https://localhost:44380/api/Timesheets/LoadLoggedUserDeputies`
it is transformed to:     `https://localhost:44380/Activities/api/Timesheets/LoadLoggedUserDeputies`or `https://localhost:44380/Reports/api/Timesheets/LoadLoggedUserDeputies`
). Even when its called by the same layout component (which was new to me, so apologies for my ignorance).

Is there any way i can always call the same url: `https://example.com/api/Timesheets/LoadLoggedUserDeputies` from every view ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a relative path to load the file:

```
$.get('api/Timesheets/LoadLoggedUserDeputies')
```

You need a slash on the front of it to make it an absolute path

```
$.get('/api/Timesheets/LoadLoggedUserDeputies')
```

that will load from the current server. If you want to specify the server, too:

```
$.get('https://example.com/api/Timesheets/LoadLoggedUserDeputies')
```